# Counting unique values in a table given they meet a certain condition

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a table which is something like this:

```
    Customer ID | Review Flag | Date Received
    London  Official    27-May-14
    London  Official    29-May-14
    Reginald    Official    29-May-14
    Reginald    Official    29-May-14    
    Townie  Official    05-Jun-14
    FHAR_L  Unofficial  05-Jun-14
    Reginald    Official    10-Jun-14
    Akmed   Official    10-Jun-14
    PALNEES Unofficial  11-Jun-14
    Akmed   Official    11-Jun-14
    Woody   Official    11-Jun-14
    Woody   Official    11-Jun-14
    Sarah   Official    11-Jun-14
```

I want to count the number of **unique official cases** over the last 2 weeks. So for example, the result for this particular table would be 5 cases and not 7.

My current implementation is to construct a pivot table, put the customer ID as the row and the value then run a count function on the value column as the ouput. The problem with this is the user needs to go in and change the filters on the pivot table every day, which can get quite confusing because we don't get a case everyday. For example, as some months have 31 days, a situation arises where if we don't receive a case on the 31st then we should not count cases received on the 30th when we are on the 13th of the next month. So ideally, I'd like this solution to be formula-based.

I've read alot about counting uniques in excel but they all seem to be confusing and complicated. Also, they seem to be based off a condition which makes it incompatible with COUNTIFS, which is the function I should use when trying to take into account 'review flag = official' and 'date range = cell1 < x <= cell2'.

Of course, I can do this in VBA but I was wondering if there is a formula-based solution available.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked it out using the `SUM(1/COUNTIFS(...))` method of counting unique items in a list.

The formula I got was: `=SUM(IF(("Official"=R18:R1000)*(D18:D1000>TODAY()-14),1/COUNTIFS(R18:R100,"Official",C18:C1000,C18:C1000,D18:D1000,">"&TODAY()-14)),0)`

Where column names R = review flag, D = date received, C = customer ID, and the dataset starts at row 18.

How I think this works: We have a left hand side array (the `IF` array) and the right hand side array (the `COUNTIFS`) array. The `COUNTIFS` array finds out the number of occurences each binding happens, i.e. at array row[10] it would ask "how many times does the 'Woody, Official, 11-Jun-14' appear together?". The left hand side array looks at which rows match our targetted conditions, returning true or false each row. The `SUM` function then adds up all the rows in the right hand side array where the left hand side array says that that particular row is `TRUE`, but as we did `1/` earlier we would get each binding summing up to only 1, thus simulating a unique.

**An Important Thing to Remember:**

When using array formulas, make sure that all your arrays are of the same size, otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: @VonC are you talking about the git question? if so - sorry, see my comment on the question (namely it's monday morning and my brain wasn't working)